# Confusion around quantifiers in intuitionistic logic

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, predicate-logic, constructive-mathematics, intuitionistic-logic

As laid out in Joel Hamkins' [A question for the mathematics oracle](http://jdh.hamkins.org/question-for-the-math-oracle/), I am interested in considering the possibility that some arithmetic sentences might not satisfy the law of the excluded middle.

Suppose such a sentence is of the form $Q = \forall n P(n)$. I imagine that, *for any given value of $n$*, I might agree that $P(n) \vee ¬P(n)$ is true, and also that $¬P(n)$ should imply $¬Q$. But that seems like it should not lead me to commit to the statement $Q \vee ¬Q$.

Similarly, suppose the sentence is of the form $Q' = \exists n P'(n)$. Then, for any given value of $n$, I might agree that $P'(n) \vee ¬P'(n)$ is true, and also that $P'(n)$ should imply $Q'$. But that seems like it should not lead me to commit to the statement $Q' \vee ¬Q'$.

I'm not familiar enough with intuitionistic logic to make this reasoning precise. Could anyone please clarify what's going on?

Comment: See [Intuitionistic Logic](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-intuitionistic/) for consequence of the rejection of LEM: for example $∃x A(x) → ¬∀x¬A(x)$ is valid in IL, while the converse is not provable.

Comment: Yes, I have seen some of these consequences before. But I still don't have enough intuition (pun not intended) for what's going on to know how to formalize the statements I described above.

Comment: For example, is an appropriate formalization of the first statement $¬((\forall n (P(n) \vee ¬P(n))) \rightarrow ((\forall n P(n)) \vee ¬(\forall n P(n))))$? I'm not sure that this is what I object to, and even if it is, all the nesting and negations have me lost when I try to think about proving it, let alone trying to understand *why* it corresponds to my "intuition" ("that seems like..." above).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key to keep in mind is that in intuitionistic logic, and more generally in constructive logic, is that something is true only if you can prove it.
In particular in order to prove a formula of the form $A \lor B$ you have to provide a proof of $A$ or a proof $B$.

With this in mind, your assumption, namely that for each $n$ the formula $P(n) \lor \neg P(n)$ is true, would mean that you have a way, an algorithm if you like, to provide for every $n$ a proof of $P(n)$ or a proof $\neg P(n)$.

Assuming that this function/algorithm exists does not provide any information on the algorithm, in particular we do not know if this algorithm returns for every $n$ a proof of $P(n)$ or if there is a $n$ for which it returns a proof for $\neg P(n)$.

Not having this information we can neither state if $\forall n P(n)$ or not nor whether $\neg \forall n P(n)$.

Hence we are left in a situation in which we are not able to prove eithr $\forall n P(n)$ or its negation, so we cannot prove $(\forall n P(n))\lor(\neg \forall n P(n))$.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, this made things much more concrete for me. So then, my formalization in the comments above is correct?

Comment: I believe that it is lacking of a braket, if I understood to which formula you are referring to.

Comment: @RobinSaunders No, it's not correct. You need to separate not provable from refutable, i.e. the negation being provable, especially as classical logic is compatible with constructive logic so you can't refute anything that is provable classically. All you can say is that $(\forall n.P(n)\lor\neg P(n))\to(\forall n.P(n))\lor\neg(\forall n.P(n))$ is not provable. This does mean you could, if you wanted to, consistently take its negation as an (anti-classical) axiom, but you could also consistently take the unnegated formula as an axiom.

Comment: @DerekElkins, thanks for this clarification. However, I'm not clear about what taking the negation of that statement as an axiom would entail. I think it doesn't say that the antecedent and consequent are incompatible, but only that it's possible in principle to have the former without the latter. So then, would this axiom only allow us to prove general statements about what cannot always be proven?

Comment: @RobinSaunders I should haven been more precise. There are certainly *some* $P$s for which the statement is provable constructively so you can't take as an axiom that the negation holds for *all* $P$. However, for any particular (or postulate) $P$ for which it is not provable, you can take the negation of the statement *for that $P$* as an axiom. (One way to think of it is it's the negation of a "second-order" quantification $\forall P.(\dots)$ which [classically] would just mean $\exists P.\neg(\dots)$.)

Comment: @RobinSaunders I think something like [Church's thesis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Church%27s_thesis_(constructive_mathematics)) would allow you to prove a negation of this statement. If so, this is much stronger than simply taking a particular instance of the negation of the formula, but it gives an example of "what it means". A realizability semantics provides a counter-model for the statement (and is a formal version of Giorgio Mossa's argument) and Church's thesis should let you internalize enough of it (essentially a variation on the Halting Problem).

Comment: @DerekElkins, thanks very much. That makes sense.